# Adding AtomicCmpXchg instruction with OCaml LLVM API

Tags: ocaml, llvm, llvm-ir, codegen

I’m trying to implement mutexes in the LLVM backend I’m writing for my programming language. I’m having trouble figuring out the exact API call, using the OCaml llvm bindings, to generate a `cmpxchg` instruction.

I'm using OCaml 4.14.0 and `llvm@14.0.6`.

In my research, I found an [example](https://gist.github.com/jrk/3948460/revisions) using a “`build_cmpxchg`,” and I also found a [definition](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/faa43a80f70c639f40021a175c60857bdcf7cc1f/llvm/bindings/ocaml/llvm/llvm.ml#L241) of `AtomicCmpXchg` as a part of an enum in LLVM’s OCaml bindings. However, I can’t find any function in these bindings that would *create* this instruction.

What am I missing? How can I tell the LLVM OCaml bindings to add this instruction?

Comment: At the moment, LLVM binding are maintained by Alan. https://discuss.ocaml.org/u/alan/
If you won't get any luck here, you may ping him on OCaml Discuss forum.